# Jmeter Console is not displaying any logs

Tags: jmeter

[Image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mwIN.png)

The jmeter console does not show any logs or print output.I am using jmeter 5.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue:

[image]

so my expectation is that your [JMeter logging configuration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) is not default, i.e. you turned logging of by accident.

I believe if you:

1. Take [log4j2.xml](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/bin/log4j2.xml) file from JMeter Github page and copy it to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the original logging configuration file

You should get the same behaviour as I do